# Proving a vector space is infinite-dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $S$ be a vector space. Suppose that for any positive integer $n$, there exists a linearly independent subset $S_n ⊆ V$ of size $n$.

How do you show that $S$ is not finite dimensional but infinite-dimensional.

I understand that to be finite dimensional then it must have a finite then  there exists a finite set that such at $\operatorname{Span}(T)=S$. So would it be right to prove by contradiction that there is not a finite spanning set that satisfies $\operatorname{Span}(T)=S$, and hence I could argue that the vector space $S$ is infinite dimensional.

How would I show that $S$ does not have a spanning set $T$, such that $\operatorname{Span}(T)=S$?

Comment: If it was finite dimensional it would have a finite basis.

Answer (score 3):

Try to prove the following statement:

> If $V$ is a vectorspace and $A = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ is a subset of $V$ containing $n$ (different) vectors. Suppose $A$ is a generating set for $V$, then every subset of $V$ with more than $n$ elements is a linearly dependent subset.

**Given:** a vector space $V$ such that for every $n \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ there is a subset $S_n$ of $n$ linearly independent vectors.

**To prove:** $V$ is infinite dimensional.

**Proof:** Let us prove this statement by contradiction: suppose that $V$ has finite dimension $k$. Fix a basis $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$, then it is given that we can find a set $S_{k+1}$ of $k +1 < \infty$ vectors which are linearly independent. However, the above statement shows that the elements have to be linearly dependent, a contradiction. Hence it must be that $V$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: How can one assume that by assumption there is a set k+1<infinity elements such that the elements are linearly independent?

Thanks

Comment: @Mathamainia see edit. If this is not clear, I will try to explain :). Also, note that I denoted the vector space by $V$, since I think using $S$ would be confusing together with the $S_n$.

Comment: Sorry would you mind please explaining

Comment: @Mathamainia have you read what I have edited? The statement you try to prove says you have a vector space $V$ such that for each $n$ there is a subset $S_n$ of $n$ linearly independent vectors. You try to prove that $V$ is infinite dimensional. I prove this by contradiction, by assuming that $V$ has finite dimension and then use that it is given that I can find a subset with more vectors which are linearly independent.

Comment: Surely any set Sk+1 of k+1<∞ vectors would be are linearly dependent by the theorem you stated above, and as we are given S is a linearly independent set of vectors then this causes contradiction and hence V is infinite dimensional. (rather than the other way)

Answer (score 0):

I will use the following definition of "finite dimensional":

> **Definition**  A vector space $V$ is finite dimensional if $V$ has a finite spanning set.  Otherwise, $V$ is infinite dimensional.

Note: the definition does not presume that we know what "dimension" means.

One has the following elementary theorem about matrices:

> **Theorem 1**  If a matrix $A$ has more columns than rows, then there exists an non-zero solution to $A x = 0$.

Proof:  Row reduction.

The theorem has the following consequence:

> **Theorem 2**  Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional with a spanning set of cardinality $n$.  Then any linearly independent set in $V$ has cardinality $\le n$.

Proof.  Suppose $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is a spanning set and $\{w_1, 
\dots, w_m\}$ is linearly independent.  Since   $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is spanning, there exist $a_{i, j}$ in the underlying field $K$ such that
$w_j = \sum a_{i, j} v_i$.  Let $A$ denote the matrix $(a_{i, j})$.  If $m >n$,  there exists $$x = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_m \end{bmatrix} \ne 0$$ such that $A x = 0$.  Check that this implies $\sum_j x_j w_j = 0$, contradicting the linear independence of  $\{w_1, 
\dots, w_m\}$.

With a tiny bit more effort, one can prove the existence of bases and that any two bases have the same cardinality:

> **Definition** A basis of $V$ is a set that is both spanning and linearly independent.
>
> **Theorem 3**  A finite dimensional vector space has a basis.

Sketch:  Choose a spanning set of minimal cardinality and show that it is also linearly independent.

> **Theorem 4**  Any two bases of a finite dimensional vector space have the same cardinality.

Proof.  Follows from Theorem 2.

> **Definition**  The cardinality of a basis is called the dimension of $V$.
>
> **Theorem**  Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space with dimension $n$.  Then any spanning set of $V$ has cardinality $\ge n$ and any linearly independent subset of $V$ has cardinality $\le n$.

Proof.  Follows from Theorem 2.

Answer (score 0):

So: assume that for every $n$ there exists a linearly independent subset $S_n$ of $V$ of cardinality $n$.  Show that there exists a countable subset of $V$ that is linearly independent.

Consider $S'_n = S_1 \cup \ldots \cup S_n$. Note that 
$$S'_1\subset S'_2 \subset \ldots$$ and inside every $S'_n$ there exists a linearly independent subset of cardinality $n$.

Now start an inductive construction.  Inside $S'_1$ there exists a linearly independent subset $S''_1$ of cardinality $1$. Suppose that we have constructed $S''_n$ inside $S'_n$ of cardinality $n$. Then we can enlarge it to $S''_{n+1}$ inside $S'_{n+1}$ of cardinality $n+1$. We obtain
$$S''_1 \subset S''_2 \subset S''_3 \subset \ldots $$
every $S''_n$ is linearly independent of cardinality $n$. 
We get $S''=\cup_n S''_n$ linearly independent and countable.