# Is $V$ infinite-dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$V$ is a vector space and for any positive integer $n$, there exists a linearly independent subset $S_n \subseteq V$ of size $n$.

Is $V$ infinite-dimensional and how do I go about proving this?

Comment: It follows directly from the definitions.

Comment: Yes. If it would be finite, say dimV=n, then $S_{n+1}$ wasn't a linear subspace.

Comment: Is your definition of "finite dimensional"  that there exists a finite *spanning* set?

Answer (score 1):

I moved my detailed answer to the question which this question duplicates.
[Proving a vector space is infinite-dimensional](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678507/proving-a-vector-space-is-infinite-dimensional)

Answer (score 0):

This is an exercise in verifying definitions and using some basic theorems, but I am guessing that this is a bit confusing when taking the first few steps into mathematics. So let's go through this together.

(Let me point out that I don't know what exactly are the definitions and theorems that you've seen. But I imagine these will be along the lines of the ones I write here. In case this is not so, you should consider this an invaluable exercise to see how to apply what we've done here to your given definitions and theorems.)

First, the definitions:

> **Definition.** A set $X$ is finite if and only if there is a natural number $n$ and a bijection $f\colon X\to\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$.

And,

> **Definition.** A vector space $V$ is *$n$-dimensional* if every basis of $V$ has size $n$. We say that $V$ is *finite dimensional* if for some $n$, $V$ is $n$-dimensional, and otherwise we say that $V$ is *infinite dimensional*.

Now we have a theorem:

> **Theorem.** The dimension of a vector space is at most $n$ if and only if every set of more than $n$ vectors is linearly dependent.

---

Now we can finally prove what we want.

**Theorem.** Suppose that for all $n$, there is $S_n\subseteq V$ which is linearly independent and of size $n$, then $V$ is infinite dimensional.

*Proof.* If $V$ is finite dimensional, then there is some $n$ such that $V$ is $n$-dimensional, but then $S_{n+1}\subseteq V$ is a set of size $n+1>n$ of linearly independent vectors. Therefore for all $n$, $V$ is not $n$-dimensional, and thus not finite dimensional, i.e. $V$ is infinite dimensional as wanted. $\quad\square$

Comment: This is a terrible definition of "finite dimensional" since it presumes invariance of dimension, which is more or less the only actual theorem in basic linear algebra.  I almost never vote down an answer, but I am really tempted here.

Comment: Well, then, how would *you* define "finite dimensional"? It's been a while since I had to dabble with linear algebra. I'm open for suggestions...

Comment: I would define "finite dimensional" by the existence of a finite spanning set.   The basic theorem is that if $V$ has a spanning set of finite cardinality $N$, then any linearly independent set has cardinality $\le N$, and this follows from the statement that a matrix with more columns than rows has non-trivial kernel.

Comment: This seem to make the proof of the theorem *much* more complicated than necessary without any auxiliary theorems about sizes of spanning sets and linearly dependent sets in finite dimensional spaces. I'll delete this answer shortly.

Comment: Or why not wait till the OP tells how he/she defines (in)finite dimensional?

Comment: @Shashi: Sure, why not.

Comment: @fredgoodman: By the way, this is why I made the point in parenthesis, and in fact if this is *not* the definition that the OP is using, I find even more pedagogical value to my answer here, since it forces the OP to sit and try this proof with their own definition, rather than copy-paste it.